# Strange JsonSerializationException while deserializing nested classes with List<Interface> members

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize some complex json (using custom converters that extend JsonConverter) that contains lists of interfaces. These lists need to be filled with class instances that implement those interfaces.

Some of these class instances also have their own `List<IInterface>` member to deserialize. Here's a snippet of this json (with parts omitted/changed for brevity). This json is valid and I do not have any control over its structure. It was made using the Jackson parser, (the server side is implemented in Java) if that matters.

`Features` is a member of a larger object I'm trying to deserialize.

```
"features": {
      "features": [
        {
          "@class": "com.company.project.business_logic.StandardFeatureArtifact",
          "feature_number": 1,
          "weight": 1,
          "player_bool": false,
          "override_bool": false,
          "play_bool": false,
          "evaluates_bool": false,
          "result_bool": false,
          "runners": [
            {
              "@class": "com.company.project.business_logic.StandardRunnableFeatureArtifact",
              "components": [
                {
                  "@class": "com.company.project.business_logic.components.GamePlayComponent",
                  "composition_order": 1,
                  "behaviours": [
                    {
                      "@class": "com.company.project.business_logic.behaviours.MultiplierBehaviour",
                      "order": 2,
                      "weight": 1,
                      "multiplier": 1
                    },
                    {
                      "@class": "com.company.project.business_logic.behaviours.RepeatActionBehaviour",
                      "order": 1,
                      "weight": 1,
                      "times_to_run": 8
                    },
                    {
                      "@class": "com.company.project.business_logic.behaviours.SymbolBehaviour",
                      "order": 0,
                      "weight": 1,
                      "symbol_to_fill": "STRING"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Features is a `List<IFeature>`
Runners is a `List<IRunnableFeature>`
Components is a `List<IRunnableComponent>`
Behaviours is a `List<IBehaviour>`

I've written custom JsonConverters for each of the above 4 member lists. Here's a snippet of one of my custom JsonConverters

```
class StandardFeatureArtifactConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return (objectType == typeof(StandardFeatureArtifact));
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JArray jo = JArray.Load(reader);
            StandardFeatureArtifact sfa = new StandardFeatureArtifact();
            sfa.Runners = new List<IRunnableFeature>();
            foreach (JObject jobj in jo)
            {
                if (jobj["@class"].ToString().EndsWith("StandardRunnableFeatureArtifact"))
                {
                    StandardRunnableFeatureArtifact srfa = jobj.ToObject<StandardRunnableFeatureArtifact>(serializer);
                    sfa.Runners.Add(srfa);
                }
            }
            return sfa;
        }
```

My `WriteJson()` just throws a `NotImplementedException()` at the moment because I'm solely focusing on deserialization first.

So here's the problem. I can deserialize to the `return sfa` line just fine. I get a valid `StandardFeatureArtifact` object, however my custom converter for Behaviors is never executed and when the `ReadJson()` method above returns, I get a `JsonSerializationException {"Error setting value to 'Runners' on 'Company.JSON.StandardFeatureArtifact'."}`.

The above exception occurs on the following line in my `FeatureConverter` class in `ReadJson()` (which is very similar to the above `ReadJson()` except `jo` in `FeatureConverter` is a `JObject`)

```
StandardFeatureArtifact sfa = jobj.ToObject<StandardFeatureArtifact>(serializer);
```

This doesn't make any sense because sfa is a valid object when I'm stepping through the `return sfa` line.

I'm positive that I'm annotating and implementing the converters correctly because I have another `List<Interface>` member (for the same outer object that `Features` belongs to) that I deserialize correctly. The difference between that and `Features` is that the former only has members of primitive types.

1. Any thoughts on what's causing that exception?
2. Why does my Behaviours converter never get executed?

My understanding of nested json deserialization is that each member is deserialized in a "depth first" manner. This order seems to hold for `features -> StandardFeatureArtifact -> StandardRunnableFeatureArtifact -> GamePlayComponent` but breaks for `Behaviours`.

Please let me know if more information is needed. This is my first post on SO. Thank you!